# Kafka producer resetting the last seen epoch of partition, resulting in timeout

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Recently my kafka producer running as a cronjob on a kubernetes cluster has started doing the following when pushing new messages to the queue:

```
{"@version":1,"source_host":"<job pod name>","message":"[Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition <topic name> to 4 since the associated topicId changed from null to JkTOJi-OSzavDEomRvAIOQ","thread_name":"kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1","@timestamp":"2022-02-11T08:45:40.212+0000","level":"INFO","logger_name":"org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata"}
```

This results in the producer running into a timeout:

```
"exception":{"exception_class":"java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException","exception_message":"org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for <topic name>:120000 ms has passed since batch creation", stacktrace....}
```

The logs of the kafka consumer pod and kafka cluster pods don't show any out-of-the-ordinary changes.

Has anyone seen this behavior before and if yes, how do I prevent it?

Comment: Hi @sigma1510 did you ever figure this out? We're having the same issue after upgrading to a newer version of Spring Boot / Kafka

Comment: @Matt Afraid not. We eventually tore down the cluster due to an unrelated issue and haven't seen this error since.

Comment: I seen the same log message which seems to correlate with one order of magnitude worse performance

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax What's the meaning of this log message?

Answer (score 1):

Reason:

> the Java API mode generator cannot connect with Kafka

Solution:

> On each server Add a sentence to the properties file

```sh
host.name = server IP;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this was already the case when the error occurred.